# NSColor colorWithPatternImage: and scaling (NSAffineTransform)

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

So the AppleDocs state that:

**The image to use as the pattern for the color object. The image is tiled starting at the bottom of the window. The image is not scaled.**
([NSColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithPatternImage%3a))

Well, except the pattern sort of *does* scale..
At least when drawing into a graphics context that is scaled up/down using `CAAffineTransform`.

However, the pattern is scaled by some *lesser* degree than the actual graphics, e.g. when drawing a filled `NSBezierPath` object and scaling the context up/down the pattern is just *slightly* scaled up/down, not by the same factor.

This is observed on OS X 10.6 - any ideas if that's a bug or some documented behaviour?

Ideally we'd like to use the same pattern scale factor no matter how big or small the scaled graphic (rect, bezierpath, ..) is.

Comment: Pattern will not set unless scaling property has been set. Can you give a sample code to support your claim?